# C# split large string with Regex.Split. Must keep delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm trying to split a wall of text into an array using regex and it's working fairly well but I don't want it to erase the delimiters I'm using. I've looked into look ahead function but I cant get it to work correctly or at all.

I have the following Regex which splits at the following combinations "Artículo #.", "Artículo ##.", 1), 2) etc and a), b), c)  and at the word "Párrafo".

```
var result = Regex.Split(text, @"(Artículo)\s[0-9](.)|(Artículo)\s[0-9][0-9](.)|[a-z](\))|[1-9](\))|[1-9][0-9](\))|(Párrafo)", RegexOptions.None);
```

I need to keep the keywords which I've used to split. For example I have the following text

```
Artículo 1. This is a test that includes : 1) Sample text 2) Sample text
```

Crrently I'm getting:

```
 This is a test that includes :
 Sample text
 Sample text
```

What I need:

```
Artículo 1. This is a test that includes :
1) Sample text
2) Sample text
```

I feel I'm getting close but any help would be great.

Comment: Instead of splitting, you could also use `Regex.Match` and *capture groups*. This way you can iterate through the matches, and look at which delimiter was used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
var text = "Artículo 1. This is a test that includes : 1) Sample text 2) Sample text";
var result = Regex.Split(text, @"(?!^)\s+(?=\bArtículo\s+[0-9]+\.|[a-z]\)|[1-9]\d?\)|\bPárrafo\b)", RegexOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
// => Artículo 1. This is a test that includes :
// => 1) Sample text
// => 2) Sample text
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/cPHqIR) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F!%5E%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3D%5CbArt%C3%ADculo%5Cs%2B%5B0-9%5D%2B%5C.%7C%5Ba-z%5D%5C%29%7C%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%3F%5C%29%7C%5CbP%C3%A1rrafo%5Cb%29&i=Art%C3%ADculo%201.%20This%20is%20a%20test%20that%20includes%20%3A%201%29%20Sample%20text%202%29%20Sample%20text).

The regex is

```
(?!^)\s+(?=\bArtículo\s+[0-9]+\.|[a-z]\)|[1-9]\d?\)|\bPárrafo\b)
```

It matches

- `(?!^)` - a location other than start of string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (if you use `\s*`, you will need to add `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` after the `Regex.Split` call)
- `(?=\bArtículo\s+[0-9]+\.|[a-z]\)|[1-9]\d?\)|\bPárrafo\b)` - a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\bArtículo\s+[0-9]+\.|` - whole word `Artículo`, 1+ whitespaces, 1+ ASCII digits, and a `.`, or
  - `[a-z]\)|` - a lowercase ASCII letter and `)`, or
  - `[1-9]\d?\)|` - a non-zero digit, then an optional digit and a `)`, or
  - `\bPárrafo\b` - a whole word `Párrafo`.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation and the code. It works perfectly!